# Use flexbox to create a responsive wrappable row of buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to make a row of buttons responsive. There can be either 3 or 2 buttons in the row. The reason I'm thinking flexbox (or maybe grid) is the solution is because the text in the buttons is internationalized and the language will vary meaning they will wrap depending on the text in the buttons, not just the screen width so I can't just write media queries that correspond to screen width.

These are the initial states with no wrapping:
The starting states (no wrapping) are either of these images (depending on 2 or 3 buttons):

[image: initial state with 3 buttons]

[image: initial state with 2 buttons]

These are the desired wrapping states when the container gets too small:

[image: Small screen with 3 buttons]

[image]

I created a fiddle that allows you to adjust the width of the box and toggle the optional button here:

[See Fiddle here to test each variant](https://jsfiddle.net/bd6keftx/)

This is the starting html, but maybe it would help to wrap the first two buttons together

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="button button1">
        This is a longer button
      </div>
      <div class="button button2">
        Optional Button
      </div>
      <div class="button button3">
        Confirmation button
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="width-button">Toggle width</button>
    <button class="toggle-button-button">Toggle optional button</button

>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is fixed and you are really using the `.narrow` class you can do like this,

```js
document.querySelector('.width-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('narrow');
});

document.querySelector('.toggle-button-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.button1').classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container.narrow {
  width: 320px;
}

.button {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 5px
    /* demo */
}

.button1.hide+.button2 {
  display: none;
}

.button3 {
  margin-left: auto;
}


.container.narrow .button1.hide,
.container.narrow .button3 {
  flex: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button button1">
    This is a longer button
  </div>
  <div class="button button2">
    Optional Button
  </div>
  <div class="button button3">
    Confirmation button
  </div>
</div>
<button class="width-button">Toggle width</button>
<button class="toggle-button-button">Toggle optional button</button>
```

otherwise you can change the `.narrow` class with media queries, something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.toggle-button-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.button1').classList.toggle('toggle');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: flex-start
  }
}

.button {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* demo */
  margin: 5px;
}

.toggle+.button2 {
  display: none;
}

.button1.toggle {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .button1.toggle{
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
}

.button3 {
  flex: 0 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .button3 {
    margin-left: auto;
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button button1">
    This is a longer button
  </div>
  <div class="button button2">
    Optional Button
  </div>
  <div class="button button3">
    Confirmation button
  </div>
</div>
<button class="toggle-button-button">Toggle optional button</button>
```

Comment: Sorry the .narrow class is just something that I'm applying to the container to show a width that would callapse the button it's not something I can actually use. I mentioned in the question the buttons will have different widths based on the language viewing the app, so the text wrapping happens at different widths, so media queries are not possible. I'll update the question to clarify that the .narrow class is just to show the smaller state.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to have comments regarding the `.narrow` class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jmancherje I've updated the answer to having the `auto` width for each button. I still keep my opinion that you'll need to use media queries for this

Comment: @jmancherje I've updated the answer with a media query solution, take a look, keep in mind the breakpoint used is random, so use as fits you better

Answer (score 0):

And idea using flexbox. Resize both containers to see the result

```css
.container {
  width: 480px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:horizontal;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  z-index:0;
  position:relative;
}


.button {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin:2px;
  position:relative;
}

.button3 {
  flex-grow:1; /* grow on wrap  */
  order:2; /* put after the pseudo element*/
}

/* this will push the confirmation button 
and will complete the first button on wrap */
.container::after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:999; /* push the last button */
  flex-basis:1px;
  background:green;
  border-radius:8px;
  position:relative;
  margin:2px 2px 2px -20px;
  z-index:-3;
}

/* hide the pseudo element when confirmation button on the first row */
.button3::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background:lightgray;
}

/* make sure the button area is big enough for the events*/
.button::after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-2;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:100%;
   width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button button1">
    This is a longer button
  </div>
  <div class="button button2">
    Optional Button
  </div>
  <div class="button button3">
    Confirmation button
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button button1">
    This is a longer button
  </div>
  <div class="button button2" style="display:none;">
    Optional Button
  </div>
  <div class="button button3">
    Confirmation button
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work in resizing, nothing changes. Only works if the `width` is changed, and the second example doesn't work as OP want to. neither the 1st example because OP wants buttons with `auto` width and not the same width